# Discrepancy in section headings between Tur and Shulchan Aruch

Tags: history, mikvah-ritual-bath, niddah, shulchan-aruch, tur

Over [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59248/4794) I asked about the source of the section headings in the Tur. In [a comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59248/who-authored-the-topic-division-headings-in-the-shulchan-aruch#comment158118_59248) it was indicated that the Tur himself assigned these headings.

In most Shulchan Aruchs that I have checked, the Tur labels Yoreh Deah simanim 197-199 as "hilchos tevillah" (as those simanim deal primarily with the laws of immersion), whereas in the Shulchan Aruch those simanim do not have a new label, and are still part of the section "hilchos niddah" which began at siman 183. (This distinction can be observed [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5386) as opposed to [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5544).)

Was this a decision of the publishers, or did the author of the Shulchan Aruch (or some other Torah authority) decide to un-name this section?

Answer (score 2):

While most of the editions of Shulchan Aruch that I checked do not have Hilchos Tevillah as a new section, I did find two editions that do have it (images below). Interestingly, both of these editions do not have a title in the middle of the page stating that Hilchos Tevillah has now begun; it's only at the top of the page where the heading changes from Hilchos Niddah to Hilchos Tevillah. Also interestingly, the first example actually begins Hilchos Tevillah from Siman 198 rather than 197.

### [Edition printed in 1662](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52659&st=&pgnum=327)

[image: Image of page of Shulchan Aruch]

### [Edition printed in 1812](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49569&st=&pgnum=377)

[image: Image of page of Shulchan Aruch]

However, [the first edition of Shulchan Aruch](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=113), printed in Venice 1565, does not have a new section for Hilchos Tevillah:

[image: Page of Shulchan Aruch]

This might point to the conclusion that some later printers added it in, perhaps to reconcile it with the Tur.